# Sampling distribution : mechanics of chi-squared variables

Tags: probability-distributions

I try to understand the mechanics of the variables that are obeying to chi-squared distributions.

To what distribution obey the square root of a chi-squared variable. For example,

$\sqrt{X}\sim \,?$

where $X\sim\chi^2$ with a degree of liberty $ = 1$.

Too, to what distribution is obeying

$X / 2 $

where $X \sim\chi^2$ with a degree of liberty $ = 2$.